# Brige a internet connection fron one computer over a serialport to another computer

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, iptables, ppp

I have two computers, one connected to the internet via ethernet, and another one that I would like to get a network connection to by serial link from the first computer.
Basically letting the first computer act as a switch and bridging a network interface to a serial interface to give the second computer network access.

```
Router <──> Computer1 <──> Serial-port <──> Serial-port <──> Computer2
```

How do I get ip address assignment (ipv4 and ipv6) to the second computer preferably automatically?

The computers is running Fedora 29 and uses iptables (do not know if it is relevant)

--

Thanks in advance

Comment: Never heard of such thing. Probably not possible. It's possible to bridge two network devices thought.

Comment: You'll need to do some searching regarding Ethernet Over Serial. There appear to be some drivers out there for Pi devices that may do something like this.

Comment: I have never done it but I've seen `TUN:` address type in `man 1 socat`. I *guess* `socat` can create a TUN/TAP device and link it to `/dev/ttyS0` on either computer. Then the serial connection acts as a wire between these devices. Next you set networking up, as if you had a wired network connection between the two computers. I expect you can automate this with systemd units and their dependencies. Maybe there is a better way, so my whole approach is like reinventing the wheel. Anyway, this should be possible.